# when progress bar show out it's changed my interface design

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I was expecting my progress bar works like this:

[image]

without changing the Interface design.

My layout is like:

[image]

after Showing the progress bar it becomes:

[image]

as you can see it has pushed the edittext and some other design to below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cenviro" />

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
                android:max="100"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logging in..."
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" />
```

how can I display the progress bar without changing the interface like the first picture that I showed?

Comment: There is no need to include progress bar in the Layout

Comment: The Image you have shown in the first one can be implemented without showing it in the Xml.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta if there is no progress bar in the layout, then what it will show?

Comment: Its because you are using relative layout.Use FrameLayout instade

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta the first image is progress dialog, but what I want is progress bar

Comment: You can use the progress bar in java code itself instead of mentioning it in Xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this layout below login button & remove your progress bar layout from there.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
                android:max="100"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Logging in..."
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, just add android:layout_centerInParent="true" and it will be perfect. Thx

Comment: Welcome buddy..!!

Answer (score 0):

remove **progressbar** from your xml file then use **progressdialog** in your java file like

when task starts

```
 private ProgressDialog dialog;
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
 dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
 dialog.show();
```

when it ends

```
 if (dialog.isShowing()) {

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: ProgressDialog is deprecated from SDK 26, i need to use progress dialog

Comment: then you can use framelayout and make progressbar's layoutgravity to center

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is your layout parent a RelativeLayout and then all the content is inside a LinearLayout?

Then, in a LinearLayout, two Views can't overlap themselves, so you should set the ProgressBar RelativeLayout outside of the LinearLayout.

Try changing your layout in this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
            android:max="100"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logging in..."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cenviro" />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" />

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" />
```

Then, you were using the `android:centerInParent = "true"` that has no effect inside of a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your progress bar in center of email and password and that's the reason when your progress bar becomes visible then pt moves your password view at below of password view

You can use a Default progress bar like this (As per your exception Image)

```
   ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityCon);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();
```

To Hide 
  if (progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();

Hope it will Solve your problem :-)